# measure uniform distribution oft discrete values

Tags: algorithm, math

I have an an array of n integer values x[] that range from low to height. There are therefore m:=high-low+1 possible values.
I'm searching now an algorithm that calculates how uniform the input values are distributed over the inteval [low,high].
It should output e.g. 1 if the values are as uniformly as possible and 0 if all x[i] are the same.

The problem now is that the algorithm has to work with n beging much lower than and also much higher than m.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for my case:

First I calculate a cummulative histogram of the values
(a discrete function that maps every possible value v of [min,max] to |{x[i], x[i]<=v}|)

Then I compute the distance to the diagonal line through the histogram (from 0,0 to m,n) in a squared way: sum up the squared distances of every point in the histogram to that line.

This algorithm does not provide a normalized norm, but works well with very few and very many samples. I only need the algorithm to compare two or more sets of values by their uniformity and this algorithm does this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), which is the maximum absolute deviation of the empirical cumulative mass function from the test cmf, which in this case is a straight line (since the test pmf is a uniform distribution).

Or you can compute the [discrepancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Discrepancy) of the data.